# Templating with strings instead of types

Tags: c++, templates, boost-variant

I want to create a class that works with many types. 
Yet, I want to instantiate an element of this class not with a type but rather with a string (e.g. using `"int"` instead of `int`) so that I don't have to make extensive dispatcher functions when using this class.

On a small class `Tab`, I tried two "solutions":

The first one:

```
template <typename T>
class Tab {
public :

  Tab(std::size_t length) {
    T* tab_[length];
    tab = tab_;
  }

  T* tab;

  T operator[](std::size_t i) {
    return tab[i];
  }
}; 

Tab getTab(std::string type, std::size_t length) {

    if (type == "int") {
      Tab<int> tab(length);
    } else if (type == "double") {
      Tab<double> tab(length);
    }

    return tab;
}
```

The second one:

```
typedef boost::variant<int, double> numeric;
typedef boost::variant<int*, double*> numeric_ptr;

class Tab {
public :

  Tab(std::string type, std::size_t length) {
    if (type == "int") {
      tab = new int[length];
    } else if (type == "double") {
      tab = new double[length];
    }
  }

  numeric_ptr tab;

  numeric operator[](std::size_t i) {
    return tab[i];
  }
};
```

Both tries don't compile. I would love to have a not-so-complicated solution to my problem.

**Edit: Why are you using strings instead of typenames in the first place?**

I have many functions that use a templated class. In each function, I can know the typename of the templated class as a string so I have to use a dispatch function like this one: https://github.com/privefl/bigstatsr/blob/master/src/colstats.cpp. If you have 20 functions like this, it's really annoying to write a dispatch function for every single one of them (and it's prone to error).

So I would rather like to create just one dispatch function for the instantiation of the class and use this function in all the functions that need an instance of this templated class.

Comment: Why not make `getTab` a function template?

Comment: @scohe001 Edited: don't compile.

Comment: @0x499602D2 It is precisely what I want to avoid. I want to template, but with strings.

Comment: @F.Privé "so that I don't have to make extensive dispatcher functions when using this class" Why would you need to make dispatcher functions?

Comment: @F.Privé: You are asking for something that is usually handled by implementing a factory function that returns a polymorphic type, not a templated type. You can use a templated class as the concrete implementation of an object instance, as long as it also implements the polymorphic interface.

Comment: @0x499602D2 See https://github.com/privefl/bigstatsr/blob/master/src/colstats.cpp for an example.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't know what a "factory function" nor a "polymorphic interface" are. Could you explain with an example?

Comment: If you are already using boost, you should have a look at boost.fusion.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy I've read https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.fusion. Not sure how it can help me?

Answer (score 5):

You may do something like:

```
template <typename T>
class Tab {
public:
  Tab(std::size_t length) : tab(length) {}

  // ...
private:
    std::vector<T> tab;
}; 

boost::variant<Tab<int>, Tab<double> >
CreateTab(const std::string& type, std::size_t length)
{
    if (type == "int") {
        return Tab<int>(length);
    } else if (type == "double") {
        return Tab<double>(length);
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("Bad type");
}
```

Comment: Seems promising. I'll try your solution tomorrow and come back to you.

Comment: **Seems I can't use `boost::variant<Tab<int>, Tab<double> >` as an element of the `Tab` class.** The compiler says that `boost::variant<Tab<int>, Tab<double> >` doesn't have the members and methods of the `Tab` class.

Answer (score 2):

I would not "template on string" and return a variant but rather template on the return type.  You can then

```
getTab<int>(17);
```

Even with this you don't need any “expensive dispatcher functions” you were referring to in your question.  You just template on the wrapped type of `Tab` as so

```
template < typename T >
void algorithm(Tab<T> const& t) { ... }
```

I also replaced the bare pointer with a `std::vector` for ease of use and memory correctness.

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class Tab {
  std::vector<T> tab;
public :

  Tab(std::size_t length) : tab(length) {}

  T operator[](std::size_t i) {
    return tab[i];
  }
}; 

template < typename T >
Tab<T> getTab(std::size_t length)
{
  return Tab<T>(length);
}

int main()
{
  auto ti = getTab<int>(17);
  auto td = getTab<double>(29);
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this can prevent me from having to dispatch strings to typenames?

Comment: @F.Privé Why are you using strings instead of typenames in the first place?  In this example there is clearly no need.

Comment: @F.Privé Unfortunately, this doesn't clarify it.  Do you want to avoid using a template class for `Tab`?  If yes, why?

Comment: A template class is OK. What I doesn't want is to make an extensive `case` statement (for all typenames that need to be supported, based on the string type) in all functions that need this class.

Comment: @F.Privé Is the string a constant expression, i.e. `"int"` or is it a runtime parameter?

Comment: The string is a constant. For example I want to map `"int"` to `int`, `"double"` to `double`, `"uchar"` to `unsigned char`, etc.